# Wait until input readonly attribute is gone

Tags: c#, selenium

While loading a page my input has a 'readonly' attribute. How to check if this attribute has been removed? I'm using Selenium with C#

My code:

```
IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("myInput"));
string inputReadOnly = input.GetAttribute("readonly");

while (inputReadOnly == "true")
        {
            inputReadOnly = input.GetAttribute("readonly");
        }
input.SendKeys("Text");
```

This code works, but i think there is more proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other way of making this code better than getting rid of your inputReadOnly variable.
If you don't use it anywhere else you could replace your while-loop by this:

```
while (input.GetAttribute("readonly") == "true")
{
    // maybe do a thread.sleep(n_milliseconds);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is by using Built-in Selenium feature called 'wait'. I'm using this code for 6+ months without any issues.

Step 1: create extension method.

```
 private static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
 public static void WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals(this IWebElement webElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
    {           
            wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
                //var x = webElement.GetAttribute(attributeName); //for debugging only
                if (webElement.GetAttribute(attributeName) == attributeValue) 
                {
                    return webElement;
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
```

Step 2: usage

```
IWebElement x = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("myInput")) // Initialization
x.WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals("readonly",null)
input.SendKeys("Text");
```

*Explanation:* This code will check every 500ms (this is default behavior of the 'wait' method) during 20 seconds, whether the "`readonly`" attribute of the specified `IWebElement` is equal to null. If after 20 seconds, it's still not `null`, an exception with be thrown. When the value has been changed to `null`, your next code line will be executed.

Comment: Can you share code of what you mean? As I know,  `ExpectedConditions` does not contain a definition for `AttributeToBe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of lines by doing something like

```
IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("myInput"));
while (input.GetAttribute("readonly") == "true");
input.SendKeys("Text");
```

You might also want to limit the time you wait for this to avoid infinite loop

```
IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("myInput"));

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

while (input.GetAttribute("readonly") == "true" && stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < timeoutInSeconds);

input.SendKeys("Text");
```

Comment: It's better to use `WebDriverWait` when working with Selenium.